# Using wildcards with "select()" in jq

Tags: wildcards, json, jq

Piping in some JSON, I want to be able to use a wildcard in the test used with `select()`:

```bash
curl example.com/json | jq  'select(.[].properties.type == "dev*")'
```

I was hoping it would print out anything with a type that starts with `dev`, for example `development`, `devel`, `devil`, but it doesn't.

Is it possible to use a wildcard with `select()` in `jq`?

Comment: Can you please post an example json, perhaps a simplified version of the actual one, which can be dumped in a file so that `cat file.json` can replace the first part of the pipeline?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might consider the [startswith()](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#startswith(str)) function.  Using your example:

```
curl example.com/json | jq '.[].properties | select(.type | startswith("dev"))'
```

Comment: is there a way to query with SQL `LIKE` clause? `LIKE '%John%'

Comment: You can use `contains`

Answer (score 5):

[As Satō Katsura shows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320153/116858), your example where you want to get all the properties that have a type thas *starts with* the string `dev` is had by the `jq` expression

```
.[].properties | select(.type | startswith("dev"))
```

However, you may do more elaborate matching with regular expressions using [the `test` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#test(val),test(regex;flags)):

```
.[].properties | select(.type | test("^dev"))
```

The `jq` utility uses the PCRE flavour of regular expressions, as implemented by the [Oniguruma regular expression library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma) (Wikipedia link).

Comment: Does `test()` support case-insensitive querying?

Comment: @mazunki It does. It allows for a second argument which can be a flag that tells it to do case-insensitive matching, as in `test("^dev"; "i")`.  See the section in the `jq` manual entitled "[REGULAR EXPRESSIONS (PCRE)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE)".